# How to use Doctrine2 Query Builder Pseudo-function objects?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Reading the Doctrine2 documentation for the Query Builder I found the following expressions:

```php
// Example - $qb->expr()->exists($qb2->getDql())
public function exists($subquery); // Returns Expr\Func instance

// Example - $qb->expr()->all($qb2->getDql())
public function all($subquery); // Returns Expr\Func instance

// Example - $qb->expr()->some($qb2->getDql())
public function some($subquery); // Returns Expr\Func instance

// Example - $qb->expr()->any($qb2->getDql())
public function any($subquery); // Returns Expr\Func instance
```

But in the documentation there isn't examples of how they work, besides the comments they put above each line that doesn't explain too much.

Could someone please explain me how to use them in a query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the information so I'm answering my own question just in case someone else is interested.

These expressions map to their corresponding DB implementations of EXISTS, ALL, SOME and ANY. The documentation for MySQL is found [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html) for "EXISTS" and "NOT EXISTS", [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html) for "ANY", "IN" and "SOME"; and [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/all-subqueries.html) for "ALL".